# how to plot a dot each time at the point the mouse is clicked in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How is it possible to plot a dot/circle at the point being clicked on in matplotlib(python 3)? Moreover i want to read the pixel value of each dot. I have tried plotting the circles but each time i read a different coordinate value, the previous circle is overwritten by the new circle. thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to register an `onclick` event with the figure. Below is an example that plots a dot where the user clicks:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylim([0, 10])

def onclick(event):
    print('button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
          (event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))
    plt.plot(event.xdata, event.ydata, ',')
    fig.canvas.draw()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much. Almost an hour of Googling and nothing worked in an Jupyter notebook except this example. I don't get the print though, not sure where Jupyter sends it... don't see it on terminal..

Comment: Only difference between what I was doing and this code is that I was trying to draw a point at event.x,event.y instead of event.xdata,event.ydata.. very confusing actually.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I have a problem running it on spyder, namely the plot reacts by printing 'button=... etc' but the point is not plotted, the plot stays empty the whole time

Comment: I changed plt.plot() by ax.scatter() without the ',' and it works for me in Spyder